# Switching wp_get_sites to get_sites

Tags: php, functions

WordPress recently depreciated [wp_get_sites()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_sites/) in favor of [get_sites()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sites/) in version 4.6. I've seen a few updates where people are pushing out changes to their code by simply switching it from wp_get_sites() to get_sites(). However, I noticed this one today:

```
$sites = wp_get_sites();

foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
...
```

to

```
$sites = ( function_exists( 'get_sites' ) ) ? get_sites() : wp_get_sites();

foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
$site = (array) $site;
...
```

What does this change do and why would it be useful over removing wp_ from the old function to use the new one? How does it work?

Where can I learn more about using the shortened version where it checks for the function and has a fallback all in one line? Is there a name for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is a great question.**

First of all, the comparison operator (?:) you're referring to is called a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). It's great for simple if/then blocks. It took me a while to get used to them, but now I use them all the time.

You can take a simple expression and return a value depending on the result of that expression.

This will put the sanitized value of `$_GET['string']` into the variable if it exists, and an empty string if it does not.

`$query_string = isset($_GET['string']) ?  sanitize_text_field($_GET['string']) : '';`

You can also echo this directly

```
echo $name != '' && isset($name) ? "Hello, " . $name : "I don't believe we've met"
```

Or put it in an array... and with booleans!

```
$my_array = array(
    'is_gt_5' => $this_number > 5 ? true : false
);
```

**Why use them here?**

The reason someone might use a fallback is because not everyone is on 4.6 yet. Writing it this way helps maintain backward and support future compatibility.